# "Compress" an array into a dictionary of form {item: occurences}

Tags: python

I have a function which takes an array of items and returns a dictionary. The keys of the returned dictionary are the original items of the array, and the values are the number of times those items appeared in the original array.

For example:

```
[2, 2, 3] --> {2: 2, 3: 1}
```

I wrote the following:

```
compress_dupes(array):
    out = {}

    for i in array:
        if i in out:
            out[i] = out[i] + 1
        else:
            out[i] = 1

    return out
```

This works. But I want to make it a little more elegant. Is there a more "pythonic" way of doing this, with comprehensions or any other way?

Comment: `outDict = dict((elem,inList.count(elem)) for elem in inList)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `collections.Counter()`

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(iterable)
```